# Mark git conflicts as resolved automatically

Tags: git, bash, rebase

During a rebase I need to mark conflicts as resolved automatically. I don't want really resolve them but just leave files with conflict marks and mark them resolved and continue rebase.

Is it possible to automatically mark conflicted files as resolved?

Edit:
Well in details: we have a big forked project(dropped history) and sometimes we need to rebase upstream changes into it. To do this I rebase a range of commits into some branch. And conflicts occure. I need to solve them but it would be more efficient to let a guy who is responsible for some piece of code solve it. To do so I want to leave conflict markers and push branch to server. Then a guy could check it out, solve conflicts and push it back.

Comment: You want to commit the files with conflict markers? Or you want to dump the conflicts by picking one or the other sides of the merge?

Comment: @EtanReisner I want to commit files with conflict markers.

Comment: That's going to mess up later merges somewhat badly I imagine. Also it will leave things really confusing to look at later. What are you *actually* trying to do here?

Comment: it doesn't seem a reasonable approach. here's a better one: https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html . if you really want that approach, i don't know how to help you

Comment: @EtanReisner During upstreaming changes I need to let other people resolve their conflicts on their machines and then merge the fixed branch into another branch.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest rerere (as "better approach") either until the TO can clearly state the intent behind leaving conflict marks. ([XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)) @s0nicYouth, do you plan to leave the conflict marks permanently or only during multiple rebases? Do you want to "have" both codes for further investigation? Are you just overwhelmed by the conflicts during rebase and want to solve them calmly afterwards?

Comment: If your Responsible Guy has access to git, just have him do the resolution directly.  Don't give him a committed file with conflict markers in it.  He may want the original objects, which he can easily get from git if he's doing the rebase resolving, but he cannot easily get from git if you've committed a bogus resolution.

Comment: Yeah, don't do this. It probably won't work. Just let the right person do the merge in the first place. That's **much** safer, better and saner.

Comment: @EtanReisner unfortunatly I think it's impossible. Rebase itself takes almost a day. If I stop every time ad call a person to my machine to resolve a conflict it would take days.

Comment: No, you misunderstood. You don't do it **at all**. You have **them** do it on **their** machine on **their** time as it seems to be **their** job to manage this. What you are asking for is going to, at best, make the eventual clean up *much* more annoying and leave the repo in *awful* state from a history perspective and, at worst, make the eventual clean up **many** times worse than it would otherwise have been and (potentially) actually unresolvable without **serious** re-engineering effort.

Comment: @EtanReisner could you please explain what you mean in more detailed way?

Comment: Explain what? **You** should not do this process. The person who can **actually** merge the changes should do so. They should do so on their time. Not your time. Doing this the way you are requesting is a **bad** idea and is **very** likely to make this process **much** harder to do correctly and **much** more likely to take **more** time, **more effort** and be more likely to be done incorrectly.

Comment: @EtanReisner I think you did not get the thing. They can't merge something on their time because I'm merging upstream into our master and do you propose to do so not in one move? During the merging I'm getting conflicts that may be anyone's and we have to solve it somehow.

Comment: No, I understand what you are doing and if that may involve multiple people that's unfortunate but doesn't change the fact that doing what you are asking is a **bad** idea and **is** going to make this more complicated in all but the **simplest** of scenarios.

Comment: @EtanReisner and how would you do a merge then?

Comment: Very painfully the first time and with `rerere` enabled to hopefully avoid much/most of said pain the next time. This may not be the best approach to maintaining this code. A single merge of the upstream code in instead of a rebase might be easier (though have a very different git repository, etc. outcome/result). Or maintain independent branches per-concern or per-person and rebase them individually and merge once that is done (though that also is going to potentially be painful to merge and maintain). I don't know that there is a "good" solution to this problem but someone else might.

Answer (score -1):

> During a rebase I need to mark conflicts as resolved automatically. I don't want really resolve them but just leave files with conflict marks and mark them resolved and continue rebase.
>
> ***Is it possible to automatically mark conflicted files as resolved?***

You have the `git rerere` command for your help.

This is exactly for this command is for.

#### [`git rerere`](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/fix-conflicts-only-once-with-git-rerere-7d116b2cec67#.d8f95i5j7)

**R**ecorded **R**eused **R**esolution

```
# enabled the option to record the 
git config --global rerere.enabled true
```

[image]

Comment: The question became clearer meanwhile: "`During upstreaming changes I need to let other people resolve their conflicts on their machines and then merge the fixed branch into another branch. `". Your answer is no longer applicable, please rework.